# About Rich Communication Suite

Tags: api, gsm

I was reading about Rich Communication Suite by GSMA, and have decided to read it further. If any one of you have any idea about

- how to build client to use its APIs or
- has any documentation/RCS APIs code
- Any links to study it deeply

Then please give me. Any type of content/idea related to RCS is highly needed by me.

Thanks for your help.

--Note : Regrets for inappropriate tag, as I am unable to find any Tag regarding this. Please add this tag to with all the tags.

Comment: I am studying RCS for extended SIP.
Here is the link of a project what i got .. >>http://code.google.com/p/boghe/ It should be helpful to build client and core. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

For building a client you will need first to get a bit familiar with the whole picture of the system you want to work with:

```
Your code                                                                   Another user                       
manages a  <==== (REST) HTTP Req/Res. =====> GSMA Infrast. <==== SIP =====>  (Native)
user
```

If you have two users registered through the API, the scheme will be the following:

```
Your code                             
manages    <==== (REST) HTTP Req/Res. =====> GSMA Infrast. <==== SIP=
Alice                                                                ||
                                                                     ||
                                                                     ||
Your code                                                            ||
manages    <==== (REST) HTTP Req/Res. =====> GSMA Infrast. <==== SIP=
Bob
```

Being this a REST API you can use any language, tool, platform, framework... Capable of issuing HTTP requests will be enough (ranging from Java with Apache HTTP Library to shell scripting with curl or wget on Linux). The documentation of the API is available here:

https://rcs.oneapi-gw.gsma.com/f/files/resources/Solaiemes_RCS_solution_GW_OMA_API_Description_v1.1.pdf

Basically, you have to register your user (setting it as available, the same than turning on your handy, nothing to do with registering on a website) and then add some contacts to work with (another user or a mobile phone registered within the GSMA Innovation Challenge with a native SIP client) as you want to use the API to communicate with somebody. You can trigger actions (you start chatting, sending files, video-sharing...) and be notified by the actions that other uses trigger towards you (some talks to you, sends you a file, video-shares...). The notifications are provided as JSON and all you have to do is parsing them. This is a simple way to describe the behaviour, if you want real knowledge check the link above (contains a precise API description and Java code samples).

I encourage you to read the document above when developing and this one to get a sharper idea of the API:

https://rcs.oneapi-gw.gsma.com/f/files/resources/GSMA_RCS_API_Developer_Guide_vs1_2.pdf

Finally an advice: you have to be conscious that you are working with an API that hides the (great) complexity of the underlying infrastructure, so be patient and don't let the frustation take over you :) I can say that after the initial gap the API is powerful and (very) easy to use.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

[gsma](/questions/tagged/gsma) [gsm](/questions/tagged/gsm) [api](/questions/tagged/api) [rcs](/questions/tagged/rcs) [sip](/questions/tagged/sip) [joyn](/questions/tagged/joyn)